# Python - Matching dictionaries with similar key-value pair

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I am trying to match dictionaries using the key `y2` of `line texts` and store them under a new dictionary key `Transaction`.

This is my input:

```
a = [[{'Line No ': '1', 'Line Bounding Box ': '(15, 2, 170, 79)', 'Lowest Confidence ': '0', 'Line texts ': [{'Column_No': '2', 'text_item': 'stuff1','y2':100}]}],[{'Line No ': '1', 'Line Bounding Box ': '(15, 2, 170, 79)', 'Lowest Confidence ': '0', 'Line texts ': [{'Column_No': '1', 'text_item': 'stuff2','y2':100}]}],[{'Line No ': '1', 'Line Bounding Box ': '(15, 2, 170, 79)', 'Lowest Confidence ': '0', 'Line texts ': [{'Column_No': '5', 'text_item': 'stuff3','y2':101}]}]]
```

This is the logic I have used:

```
sorted_lst = []

''' Getting each dict row by row '''
for i in a:
    #print(i)
    x = (i[0]['y2'])
    #print(x)
    sorted_lst.append(x)
    #print(sorted_lst)
    sorted_lst = sorted(list(set(sorted_lst)))
    c = []
    for k in sorted_lst:
        temp_dict1 = {}
        if x == k:
            temp_key1 = "column" + i[0]["Column_No"]
            temp_dict1[temp_key1] = i[0]["text_item"]
            #print(temp_dict1)
        c.append({'y2':k,'Transactions':temp_dict1})
from pprint import pprint

pprint(c)
```

This is the current output where its printing null for first matching dictionary:

```
[{'Transactions': {}, 'y2': 100},
 {'Transactions': {'column5': 'stuff3'}, 'y2': 101}]
```

This is the desired output:

```
[{'Transactions': {'column2': 'stuff1',
                   'column1': 'stuff2'},
  'y2': 100},
 {'Transactions': {'column5': 'stuff3'},
  'y2': 101}]
```

Where exactly am I going wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the list items inside `a` has only one dictionary as their corresponding item, we may first append all different `y2` values in a list and thereafter check looping through the list `a` searching for the value  for the `y2` key inside `'Line texts '` key inside the dictionary as the sole item of the list inside list `'a'`.

Try this :

```
a = [[{'Line No ': '1', 'Line Bounding Box ': '(15, 2, 170, 79)', 'Lowest Confidence ': '0', 'Line texts ': [{'Column_No': '2', 'text_item': 'stuff1','y2':100}]}],[{'Line No ': '1', 'Line Bounding Box ': '(15, 2, 170, 79)', 'Lowest Confidence ': '0', 'Line texts ': [{'Column_No': '1', 'text_item': 'stuff2','y2':100}]}],[{'Line No ': '1', 'Line Bounding Box ': '(15, 2, 170, 79)', 'Lowest Confidence ': '0', 'Line texts ': [{'Column_No': '5', 'text_item': 'stuff3','y2':101}]}]]
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(i[0]["Line texts "][0]['y2'])
b = sorted(list(set(b)))
print(b) # [100, 101]
c = []
for k in b:
    temp_dict ={}
    for i in a:
        if i[0]["Line texts "][0]['y2'] == k:
            temp_key = "column" + str(i[0]["Line texts "][0]["Column_No"])
            temp_dict[temp_key] = i[0]["Line texts "][0]["text_item"]
    c.append({"Transactions" : temp_dict, "y2" : k})
print(c)
"""
[{'Transactions': {'column1': 'stuff2', 'column2': 'stuff1'}, 'y2': 100},
 {'Transactions': {'column5': 'stuff3'}, 'y2': 101}]
"""
```

Your code should have given `KeyError` as for the list item of `a` is another list of a single dictionary as an item without any key `'y2'`, but you're trying to access the non-existant key of the bigger dictionary.